# Form submit, downloads php

Tags: php, html, apache

WHen I submit this form it downloads the php script that it refers to. Is it porblem in the code?
HTML:

```
  <form action="control.php" method="post" id="target">
        <input id="pass" value="You shall not pass!" name="pass" />
        <input type="submit" style="display:none;"/>
    </form>
```

control.php:

```
<?php
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
?>
```

Comment: That would be a problem with the server configuration if the browser gets a download on all .php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server sounds like it isn't configured to serve PHP files properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your website is forcing your browser to download PHP files, Apache obviously doesn't recognise PHP as a valid file type. You might need to reconfigure httpd.conf so that it acknowledges PHP and its installation directory.

Check out [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Most probably is your server configuration, have you checked that PHP is installed properly and mod_php is enabled in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good.

Create Phpinfo.php and use the following code:

```
    <?php

    // Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
    phpinfo();

    // Show just the module information.
    // phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
    phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

    ?>
```

Run the website and use the information provided to troubleshooting your settings, if php does not run, it will not display the page, and will most likely not be installed and/or configured properly.

Reference: [PHP Manual - phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: oh, I can even run it. It just downloads th ephp file

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned above you need to verify you have a web server like apache and then install the php package. If you have admin rights on the box.