# Form tag in my react application downloads php file. How to fix?

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, webserver

I am developing a react application which gives information about travel attractions in that country which user selects.

Currently, my app coummnicates to the server with `<form>` tag.

This is my react code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
submitForm = (e)=>{
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <section id="Search" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                <form action="/public/server/search.php" method="GET">
                    <input placeholder="search country, attraction names" type="text" name="search"/>
                    <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                </form>
            </section>
            <ItemList/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

php file: This is just test code. For checking if my php file works.

```
<?php
 $message = "wrong answer";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
?>
```

There is no problem with the URL.

Problem is when a user submits, the browser downloads php file instead of running it.

I googled and found that if it downloads, there is some problem with my webserver configuration.

[Submit button is downloading the php instead of running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398684/submit-button-is-downloading-the-php-instead-of-running-it)

and

[Form submit, downloads php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935677/form-submit-downloads-php)

But how can I fix the configuration problem whem I am running the file and localhost with npm start? not Apache? or is it same?

I tried to run my file with apache webserver (I already have XAMPP) but it shows 404 error because it doesn't find bundle.js (webpack file).

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "ReactExample",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode 
   development"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
"webpack": "^4.16.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ]
},
"dependencies": {
  "classnames": "^2.2.6",
  "react": "^16.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "redux": "^4.0.0"
}
}
```

Comment: umm... what are you expecting to happen when the form submits. you're not expecting it to `alert` are you?

Comment: @azium alert code is just for checking if my php file works. Later, when user submits, server needs to get value from the input field and check if my database has some item with that value

Comment: but where would the alert appear to see that its working? that php file can't echo the script back to your react app

Comment: in any case, you should be making an ajax call to your php server, not trying to execute a script

Comment: @azium but doesn't it echo script file into the DOM? Anyway, later I will remove the alert and do logics with database. Now, I need to do something to fix  downloading issue.. After solving it, I can see if php works or not ..

Comment: you're getting confused about where this code is running. React is a CLIENT side library. it is only executing in the context of the browser. php is SERVER side. it can only do whatever a server can do, which clearly it cannot inject anything to a DOM that is running on a completely different environment / computer. You need to run a php server separately and expose a REST endpoint that your client side application will communicate with via ajax (fetch / xhr)

Comment: @azium Sorry for late comment, forgot to say thank you for nice advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request going to your webserver usually hits `index.php` or `.html` and so on.

With a standard webserver configuration the index file needs to be located in your webservers root directory which is, if you are using xampp, the htdocs/ directory. So basically you can only run one project with the standard configuration. if you have to run multiple projects you have to configure the vhosts for apache.

Well what happens is that you are trying to hit "http://localhost:80/public/server/search.php" with your request and expect php to execute this file but in fact, the only entrypoint to your application is the index file in your root directory.

So to clarify, all these links below are actually hitting the servers `index.php` and not any `.php` files in subdirectories:

- http://awesomedomain.com/posts/show/1
- http://awesomedomain.com/contact
- http://awesomedomain.com/downloads/catpics

There is a configuration file called `.htaccess` (apache specific) which takes care of alot of things, a few of them are passing parameters to the entrypoint and rewriting the actual url. (if configured)

So what you can do is... just hit your `index.php` which should be located in the htdocs/ directory instead of /public/server/search.php and return some values of your choice.

Don't get confused by modern frameworks where the `index.php` is located in a subdirectory, it's just a more secure approach and the entrypoint can be configured.

The main XAMPP configuration files are located as follows:

apache configuration files:

- \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
- \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

php configuration file:

- \xampp\php\php.ini

mysql configuration file:

- \xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

Comment: yw. have a nice one